# Using a String in run configurations as an argument and using it in an if-statement

Tags: java, string, if-statement, args

The code below works as long as the argument in the run configuration equals "-output". But when the arguments are empty the compiler throws and ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

The point of this piece of code would eventually be to;
- Perform an action when -output is written in the run configurations arguments
- Perform something else if the arguments are empty or different from -output

I found many problems that looked like this one. But I've been working on a solutions for far to long, so I started a new post. Help is very much appreciated.

```
...
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Version_5 v5 = new Version_5("Test");
        {
            if(args[0].equals("-output")){
                System.out.println("It works");
            }
        }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if you have arguments first, that's all.

```
if ((args.length > 0) && (args[0].equals("-output")) {
    ...
```

You might also consider using an argument-parsing library, of which there are several.

What are the extra brackets for?

Comment: The extra brackets around "Test"? They're just there because this is a copy paste from my actual code and the constructor needs an argument that is a String. To be clear: it has nothing to do with my question. So don't worry. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @Ype No, those aren't extra. The `{}` around the whole part with the commnad-line args.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see String `args[]` is an array with a specific size. If you don't pass an argument the size is zero. Before you check what is at `args[0]` check if args has a size with `args.length`.

```
if (args.length>0){
   //do something
}
else if (args[0].equals("-output")){
   System.out.println("It works");
}
```

Comment: Same same but different. :) Thanks for helping out.